# gameobject deforms when rotation changes unity

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

I have made a cubic character and i'm trying to change his head's rotation, but when the head is attached to the body, it horribly deforms. however, it seems to work just fine when i change the rotation while the head is outside the body

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> *but when the head is attached to the body*

are you referring to the parent-child object relationship or it is somehow rigged and animated? if you are referring to the parent-child relationship, i would rotate the head(which is the child) "Locally" .

try to use `transform.localRotation`

For more information about rotating a child transform use this solution as your reference : 
https://community.unity.com/t5/Scripting/How-to-rotate-a-child-transform-independent-of-parent/td-p/1633075

Comment: edit: i've got a better solution. i've made empty gameobject between the parent and the head and scaled it up with the head.